# Remover quadrados cinzas do meu programa em Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu gostaria de remover esses quadrados cinzas de meu programa.

[image: Quadrados cinza]

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import time
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()
root = Tk()
root.title("SISTEMA DE VENDAS")
root.geometry('1366x768+0+0')

root.configure(background='yellow')
FrameABC = Frame(root, bg="grey", bd=20, relief=RIDGE)
FrameABC.grid()

#============================================================

lblDate = Label(FrameABC,text="\tSupermercados Rena\t",font=('arial',30,'bold'),padx=9, pady=9,
    bd=14,bg="Cadet Blue",fg="Cornsilk", justify=CENTER).grid(row=0, column=0)

lblDate = Label(FrameABC,text="\tData: \t",font=('arial',30,'bold'),padx=9, pady=9,
    bd=14,bg="Cadet Blue",fg="Cornsilk", justify=LEFT).grid(row=1, column=0)

lblDate = Label(FrameABC,text="\tHoras: \t",font=('arial',30,'bold'),padx=9, pady=9,
    bd=14,bg="Cadet Blue",fg="Cornsilk", justify=LEFT).grid(row=2, column=0)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Para o `label` que você adicionou fique com o tamanho total é possível você utilizar uma propriedade do `grid()` chamada `sticky` que serve para você "grudar" seu objeto(seja button, label e outros) na direção que desejar.

A propriedade `sticky` recebe uma string como parâmetro, se quiser "grudar" para cima por exemplo seria "N" de "North"(Norte).

Propriedades do Sticky

- N: Norte (Cima)
- E: Leste (Direita)
- S: Sul (Baixo)
- W: Oeste (Esquerda)

**OBS:** Você pode unir mais de uma direção para deixar como deseja, portanto podemos usar uma string assim => "NSEW" que "grudará" em todas as direções.

No seu caso basta adicionar o `sticky` ao grid, ficando assim:

```
lblDate = Label(FrameABC,text="\tData: \t",font=('arial',30,'bold'),padx=9, pady=9,
    bd=14,bg="Cadet Blue",fg="Cornsilk", justify=LEFT).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky  =  "NSEW")

lblDate = Label(FrameABC,text="\tHoras: \t",font=('arial',30,'bold'),padx=9, pady=9,
    bd=14,bg="Cadet Blue",fg="Cornsilk", justify=LEFT).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky  =  "NSEW")
```

[TESTE DO RESULTADO](https://repl.it/@sant0will/IndolentKnobbyHexadecimal)

[Mais informações](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_grid.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Você quer remover somente a cor, certo? Se sim, basta mudar a cor "grey" desse ponto:

```
root.configure(background='yellow')
FrameABC = Frame(root, bg="grey", bd=20, relief=RIDGE)
FrameABC.grid()
```

Deixando assim:

```
root.configure(background='yellow')
FrameABC = Frame(root, bg="Cadet Blue", bd=20, relief=RIDGE)
FrameABC.grid()
```

Mas se você quer remove-los definitivamente, Você pode esticar os botões, dando a possibilidade dele se expandir ocupando os espaços livre como comentou o **sant0will**